# Render data on view?

Tags: json, codeigniter

Sorry for asking such a basic question. I am new to JSON and clueless about how to use it in Codeigniter.

I am getting some JSON response and successfully able to `echo` it on my page from controller class.
**Code**

```
function index() 
{
 $this->load->spark('restclient/2.1.0');
 $this->rest->initialize(array('server' => 'http://someurl.com/'));
 $this->rest->option(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
 $repos = $this->rest->get('query?q=someparameter');
 $data['items'] = json_encode($repos, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
 echo $data['items']; //works fine
 $this->load->view('index',$data);
}
```

**JSON Structure**

```
-ProductsAPI{
   status: 200,
   products: [
        - {
           merchant: "Newegg",
           id:"111",
           img:"someimage.jpg"
          }
        - {
           merchant: "Newegg2",
           id:"112",
           img:"anotherimage.jpg"
          }
```

**Question**
When I did this `<p><?php echo $products.ProductAPI.status ?></p>` in view I have got PHP error.

 How would I traverse through to JSON response?
Do I need to `json_decode()` my JSON response before sending it to the view?

Comment: in php the property access operator is `->` not `.`

Comment: If your response is already JSON then use `$data['items'] = json_decode($repos)` and access your products as an array of objects

Answer (score 0):

The function [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) turns an array into a string. So, in order to be able to access the content as an array (or as an object), you'll have to [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the variable again.

```
// decoding json-encoded string into an array
$arr = json_decode($var, true)

// decoding json-encoded string into an object
$obj = json_decode($var)
```

Hope this helps!